# After sorting a jtable how can I number a column?

Tags: java, swing

Hello am developing a Java Desktop result system I have succeeded in sorting my J table with respective to the column average Am still trying to give positions to the students after the J table has been sorted so that each student gets his  or her position basing on his or her average this is what I have done so far..`

```
//Sorts j Table basing on column  average 

public void checkPosition(){
    //Erases column s/no
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(0);

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(jTable1.getModel());
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);

    List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>(2000);
    sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(jTable1.getColumnCount()-2, SortOrder.DESCENDING));

    //sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    positionInsert();
}

public void  positionInsert(){
    //Inserts position at last column "position"
    int pos=1;
    for(int g=0; g<jTable1.getRowCount(); g++){
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel(); 
      model.setValueAt(pos, g, jTable1.getColumnCount()-1);
      pos++;
    }
}
```

However it still doesn't work the position is still faulty [Screenshot of j table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tUIb.png)

The table  is seen at the link above my english is not that good but help will be much appreciated thanks

Comment: "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates." See tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

Comment: Thanks Kindly be alittle more descriptive with comments code please

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int- (This is just above the the quoted line on the linked tutorial...)

Answer (score 1):

When you sort a table the data in the table model doesn't change, only the order in which the data is displayed in the table.

```
  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel(); 
  model.setValueAt(pos, g, jTable1.getColumnCount()-1);
```

The above code assumes that the data in the model is in the same order as the table which is wrong when you sort of filter a table.

You need to update the data in the model via the table:

```
  table.setValueAt(pos, g, jTable1.getColumnCount()-1);
```

The table will now convert the row of the table to the row of the model before updating the model.

Or if you want to update the model directly, you are responsible for converting the table row to the model row. This is done by using the `convertViewToModel(...)` method of the JTable.